# Java get integer input method requires the input twice

Tags: java, input

here is the Menu class

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {
    private String[] menu_options;

```
public Menu(String[] menu_options) {
    this.menu_options = menu_options;
}

public int getUserInput() {
    int i = 1;
    for (String s : this.menu_options) {
        System.out.println(i + ". " + s);
        i++;
    }

    int selection = getint_input(menu_options.length);
    return (selection);
}

private int getint_input(int max) {
    boolean run = true;
    int selection = 0;

    while (run) {
        System.out.print("Select an option: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        if (in.hasNextInt()) {
            int value = in.nextInt();
            if(value>=1 || value<=max){
                selection = value; //fixed this now working
                run = false;    
            }

        } else {
            System.out
                    .print("Invalid input. Please enter a integer between 1 and "
                            + max + ": ");

        }
    }
    return selection;
}
```

}

and here is the menudriver i was using

public class Menutester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] menuitems = new String[2];
    menuitems[0] = "option one";
    menuitems[1] = "option two";
    Menu tm = new Menu(menuitems);
    int choice  = tm.getUserInput();
    System.out.println("Got input");
}
```

}

the first time i input something it dosn't regester at all and when i try to debug it in eclipse it gives me the error FileNotFoundException(Throwable).(String) line: 195 on the first input.

this is what it returns

1. option one
2. option two
   Select an option: 1(i entered this and pressed enter)
   1(same here only it regestered the input)
   Got input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nextInt` reads the input and removes it from the buffer. You can't call it like that without storing the value.

Call it once, store the value, and then do all the checks needed.

Change this:

```
if (in.hasNextInt() && in.nextInt() >= 1 || in.nextInt() <= max) {
            selection = in.nextInt();
//...
```

for this:

```
if(in.hasNextInt()) {
   int selection = in.nextInt();
   if(selection >= 1 || selection <= max) {
       run = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: alright, i did fix that and updated my code. Thanks for the help, but it still requires two inputs when i run it. it runs like this, i changed the driver to print out the value once it gets it  <br/> 1. option one
2. option two  <br/>
Select an option: 1(my input, nothing happened)  <br/>
1(my input)  <br/>
1 (the computer printed out my selection now)  <br/>                                    sorry im having trouble formatting this comment

Comment: you're still calling `nextInt` twice so... two inputs.

Comment: edited the fixed code with a better version. The second assingment wasn't even needed.

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
   if (in.hasNextInt() && in.nextInt() >= 1 || in.nextInt() <= max) {
        selection = in.nextInt();
        run = false;
        System.out.println(run);

    }
```

as:

```
int input = in.nextInt();
if (input  >= 1 || input  <= max) {
    selection = in.nextInt();
    run = false;
    System.out.println(run);
}
```

and try it again.